# RDS's backup retention period at AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I set RDS instance's backup retention period is 7 days. I am assuming my database instance will be backuped at every 7 days. But now it is taken snapshots everyday.

How can I modify at my RDS instance so that it is taken snapshot only once in a week.

Answer (score 3):

From [Working With Backups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html):

> Automated backups occur **daily** during the preferred backup window.

You can also set the **backup retention period** for these automated backups.

If you wish to have **backups performed weekly**, you will need to trigger **manual snapshots**, which are retained until you delete them. You can trigger manual snapshots via the management console, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or via an API call.

You could also configure Amazon CloudWatch Events to trigger an AWS Lambda function that makes the API call, thereby not requiring a server to trigger the backup.